# WebSocket Implementation in Android using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, websocket

I am trying to implement simple message transferring using web sockets in android using Kotlin.
I am new to kotlin and migrated my code manually from a working java code.
But my code does not work, nothing shows - even after using the `network_security_config` as

```
<network-security-config>
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" >
</base-config>
```

And my code for the websocket implementation is ->

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var client: OkHttpClient
    private var startButton: Button? = null
    private var outputText: TextView? = null


    private inner class EchoWebSocketListener : WebSocketListener() {
        private var NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS: Int = 1000

        override fun onOpen(webSocket: WebSocket, response: Response) {
            webSocket.send("Hola there!")
            webSocket.send("cool")
            webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS,"GoodBye!!")
        }

        override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, bytes: ByteString) {
            output("Receiving "+ bytes.toString())
        }

        override fun onClosing(webSocket: WebSocket, code: Int, reason: String) {
            webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS, null)
            output("Closing : "+ code + "/" + reason)
        }

        override fun onFailure(webSocket: WebSocket, t: Throwable, response: Response?) {
            output("Error : " + t.message)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        startButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.start)
        outputText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.output)
        client = OkHttpClient()
        startButton!!.setOnClickListener{
            start()
        }
    }

    private fun start() {
        val request: Request = Request.Builder().url("ws://echo.websocket.org").build()
        val listener: EchoWebSocketListener = EchoWebSocketListener()
        val ws: WebSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, listener)
        client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown()
    }

    private fun output(s: String) {
        runOnUiThread({
            object : Runnable {
                override fun run() {
                    outputText!!.setText(outputText!!.text.toString() + "\n\n" + s)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I didn't dive too much on your code, but from first look, it looks like you're closing the connection as soon as you get the onOpen event.  I assume that may be your problem.